# Routing error in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have stumbled upon a curious behavior in ASP.NET MVC Routing.

In my RouteConfig file, when I map a route like this (the default route):

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

Using:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Home")
```

I get a nice, clean and short URL, like: `http://mysite/`

But if I add another optional parameter after `id`, like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",
            defaults: new {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                name = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

The same `ActionLink` outputs this URL: `http://mysite/home/index` every time. I verified the same behavior using `RedirectToAction`.

My questions are: Is there a way to work around this and get the shorter URL in the later case? Why ASP.NET MVC Routing engine behaves differently in these cases?

**EDIT**

I managed to work around this issue following the instructions posted by Dave A. I added a custom route before the "Default" route that matches my custom URL pattern.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Custom",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Comment: where are you rendering these routes? Are you always venturing from /Home/Index?

Comment: I tried from different actions/controllers and always got the same results in both cases.

Comment: There are indeed "bugs" or inefficiencies in the way the MVC framework handles routes. In this case, especially, it is trying to make best use of all params but getting confused. Read this post by hacked that shows more "glitches" in the system http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx

Comment: I believe System.Web.Routing mechanism is same in .NET 4 and .NET 4.5. The issue is related with routing and MVC 3/4. You can get the detail and a temporary fix at, http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/12/26/routing-issue-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx.

Comment: @DaveA Thanks! You should post this as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are indeed "bugs" or inefficiencies in the way the MVC framework handles routes. In this case, especially, it is trying to make best use of all params but getting confused.

Read this post by hacked that shows more "glitches" in the system http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/12/26/routing-issue-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx